# Qgis2threejs Exporter

Tags: web-service, qgis2threejs

I tried to export web, but the exaggeration seem to be funny as attached pictures.

What I did is I imported DEM file and then in Qgis2threejs Exporter it had the canvas map under DEM. When I checked box DEM, it showed it shows that exaggeration raises from the canvas map, I did not even set exaggeration (1.00).

Is anyway to do it without canvas map?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not exaggerated but simply a region that is not at 0m height so the canvas "level" is way below the elevation of your region of interest.

The nicest approach to me is cutting out the region of interest with a polygon layer. You can find this option in the raster layer properties in Qgis2threejs: "Clip DEM with polygon layer"

[image]

[image]

[image]